# Building Qt Shared library on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries

I've followed the instructions in the link below (and some threads here)
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html

I'm building a project successfully, but I only see the usual objects and the final binary after compilation.  Nothing that looks like a library at all.

Ideas?

MyWidget_global.h

```
#ifndef MY_WIDGET_GLOBAL_H
#define MY_WIDGET_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(MY_WIDGET_LIBRARY)
#  define MY_WIDGET_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MY_WIDGET_IMPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif
```

The project file

```
DEFINES += MY_WIDGET_LIBRARY

# Input
HEADERS += MyWidget_global.h \
            MyWidget.h
# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp \
            MyWidget.cpp
```

And finally the header of the actual class

```
#ifndef MY_WIDGET_H
#define MY_WIDGET_H

#include "MyWidget_global.h"

class MY_WIDGET_EXPORT MyWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget();
    // Snip
};

#endif
```

Comment: Do you have `TEMPLATE = lib` in your `.pro` file?

Comment: I definitely don't. I'm home from work for the weekend but will try that first thing Monday. Thanks. :)

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.   Feel free to offer it as an answer and I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt comes with a series of predefined project templates. Directly from the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html):

> The TEMPLATE variable is used to define the type of project that will be built. **If** this **is not declared** in the project file, **qmake assumes that an application should be built**, and will generate an appropriate Makefile (or equivalent file) for the purpose.

Hence, in your case, QMake assumes that an application was meant to be build. Adding the right template solves the problem, i.e.

```
TEMPLATE = lib
```

is the solution. Indeed `lib` is the correct template to create an output makefile for a library.

See [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) for a correct creation of a library and its addition to a project.

Comment: Thanks. I had gone over that documentation but missed that.  Also worth noting, when I wanted to link a static library on the Windows side, this had to be TEMPLATE = staticlib (which builds both .dll and .a libraries).